# picasso loading image somtimes,how to fix it?

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

I use Picasso library in my codes,it load image sometimes
i charge image like this

```
public class BannerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BannerAdapter.BannerViewHolder> {
    private List<Banner> banners = new ArrayList<> ( );

    public void setBanners(List<Banner> banners) {
        this.banners = banners;
        notifyDataSetChanged ( );
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BannerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent , int viewType) {
        return new BannerViewHolder ( LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext ( ) ).inflate ( R.layout.item_banner , parent , false ) );

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BannerViewHolder holder , int position) {
        holder.bindBanners ( banners.get ( position ) );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return banners.size ( );
    }

    public class BannerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView bannerImageView;

        public BannerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super ( itemView );
            bannerImageView = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.iv_itemproduct_productimage );
        }

        public void bindBanners(Banner banner) {
            Picasso.get ( ).load ( banner.getImage ( ) ).into ( bannerImageView );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain your problem please.

Comment: when i open my app picture load sometimes  or load very late maybe after 20 secound

Answer (score 0):

turn on Picasso logs using `Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true).` 
You will probably see an error message with a reason there.

Comment: i use Picasso CallBack but no error occured,it confused me.